# What is the acceleration rate of a neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, acceleration, neutrinos, cosmic-rays

I understand that photons do not have acceleration because they are massless. But what about neutrinos, which have been proven to have mass due to oscillation? Let's assume a typical Solar neutrino with an energy of 1 MeV.

Related question: what is the acceleration rate of the [Oh-My-God particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle)?

Comment: Particles accelerate only when forces act on them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Why do you ask specifically about a neutrino? It's a massive particle, and it will accelerate just as any other would, mainly due to gravitational effects, since all known flavors of neutrinos are electrically neutral.

Comment: acceleration is given by dp/dt,  (p a vector) .Are you asking about acceleration due to gravity?  In special  and general relativity photons also get accelerated in gravitational fields (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens)

Comment: I'm just curious how long it takes a neutrino to accelerate to 0.999999c (or whatever speed a typical neutrino would have) from its moment of creation.

Comment: @iyuaeo: it's typical for particles to be created at relativistic speeds (in the center of mass frame), since they are being generated by fusion in the first place.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer so there is no acceleration? The neutrino just starts out at 0.999999c?

Comment: Quantum particles do not have classical trajectories. It is impossible to say how fast it is going at its point of creation, because of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: @iyuaeo The elementary particles leave with a fixed energy momentum vctor  after an interaction. The sun  neutrinos have the energy they were created with, unless inrtracting with the gravitational field , a new interaction,  which will be very small due to their tiny mass.

Comment: BTW, the (rest) mass of an electron neutrino is suspected to be a little under [0.120 eV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino), so a 1 MeV neutrino has a Lorentz $\gamma$ factor of around 9 million, and thus a speed around 0.99999999999999 *c*. Our current [best detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector) can detect 0.233 MeV neutrinos.

Comment: *How* did you propose to accelerate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neutrino is a little like a bullet. It is launched at high speed, and not much happens after that.

A neutrino is only affected by gravity and the weak force. It is not affected by electromagnetism or the strong force.

All the everyday forces we experience are gravity and electromagnetism. These forces are long range forces.
$$F_{gravity} = G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

$$F_{electrostatic} = 4\pi \epsilon_0 \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$

where $r$ can be as big as you like.

By contrast, the strong and weak forces are short range. They are a little like Velcro. The force is present when things are very close together, but gone when separated even a little. Their range is far smaller than the diameter of an atom. Typically, they act within the nucleus of an atom.

Gravity will slow a neutrino as it escapes from the Sun. But a relativistic particle is going so fast that this is not a significant effect.

Neutrinos very seldom interact with matter. The odds are overwhelming that for any Solar neutrino detected on Earth the detection is the first interaction since leaving the Sun.

So the neutrino arrives with just about the same speed it had when it was created by a nuclear reaction in the core of the Sun.

When dealing with such short distances and small particles, everyday Newtonian mechanics does not describe it well. So it isn't right to say that the neutrino accelerated from a speed of $0$ over a distance no more than the diameter of a proton or so. It is better to say that creating the neutrino left it in a state where it had that energy. From the mass of the neutrino (which we don't know very well) you could figure out a speed. Given that the mass is very small, the speed is very close to c.

Comment: Thanks. Similar to how a photon starts off at _c_, a neutrino starts off at ~0.999999999 _c_, if my understanding of what you're saying is correct.